# Set border around UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to apply two types of border on a `UIImageView`:

1. One is the border on the `layer` of the `UIImageView`.
2. Second is the border around the `layer` of the `UIImageView`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try

```
#define kBorderWidth 3.0
#define kCornerRadius 8.0
CALayer *borderLayer = [CALayer layer];
CGRect borderFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, (imageView.frame.size.width), (imageView.frame.size.height));
[borderLayer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
[borderLayer setFrame:borderFrame];
[borderLayer setCornerRadius:kCornerRadius];
[borderLayer setBorderWidth:kBorderWidth];
[borderLayer setBorderColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
[imageView.layer addSublayer:borderLayer];
```

And don't forget to import QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h

This example will draw a boarder on the layer, but change it's frame slightly to make the border around the layer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I tried this code but it create border inside the UIImageView but I want to set the border from outside of UIImageView.

Comment: Just change the frame to whatever amount 'outside' you like:

        CGRect borderFrame = CGRectMake(-1.0,
                                        -1.0,
                                        imageView.frame.size.width+2.0,
                                       imageView.frame.size.height+2.0);

Comment: Make sure to set clipsToBounds to false, if you're trying to put the border outside the imageView

Comment: What about circular images, where you have to enable clipToBounds?

Answer (score 9):

Another way

You must import

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Then add code for your UIImageView

```
imgView.clipsToBounds = YES;
imgView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
imgView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
imgView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
```

Comment: That creates only one layer of border, the OP asks for two.

Comment: simple and elegant. the perfect solution

Answer (score 2):

An other way is to add another layer that goes a bit outside of the UIImageView's layer like so :

```
CALayer * externalBorder = [CALayer layer];
externalBorder.frame = CGRectMake(-1, -1, myView.frame.size.width+2, myView.frame.size.height+2);
externalBorder.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
externalBorder.borderWidth = 1.0;

[myView.layer addSublayer:externalBorder];
myView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

***Beware*** when using a **UIImageView**; `masksToBounds = false` means the image will spill over

```
let outsideBorder = CALayer()
outsideBorder.frame = CGRect(x: -1, y: -1, width: myView.frame.size.width+2, height: myView.frame.size.height+2)
outsideBorder.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
outsideBorder.borderWidth = 1.0

myView.layer.addSublayer(outsideBorder)
myView.masksToBounds = false
```